# Firefox redraw very slow (5 secs)

Tags: javascript, css, performance, firefox, lazy-loading

I'm developing a lazy scroll table with resizeable columns. It retrieves data from the server if the user is scrolling to a position where the data is not loaded yet. Because I want to the user to be able to scroll million of rows, I actually only put two list of 32 items in the DOM. If once of these lists scrolls out-of-the-viewport, I put it back on the other side of the visible list and refresh the items.

This all works great in Chrome, but Firefox (on ubuntu linux) gives me headaches, as it only redraws the screen after 5 seconds instead of instantly.

Does anybody know why FireFox behaves like that and maybe also how to fix/prevent this?

[EDIT]
The code finishes very quickly, I can see that in the console where I log the actions. The javascript places some nodes in the DOM. When inspecting the elements, their properties are ok, so the layout-calculation seems to be done and OK.

I will try to factor out the specific code, as it works together with the server to generate settings and some events. (I use Wicket, and refresh each of the two lists by Wicket ajax. Wicket then renderes html and replaces the dom-entries). This makes it somewhat complicated.

Comment: You should probably include some code. Also, measure what is actually taking so long, making the AJAX requests, generating the table or inserting it in the DOM.

Comment: So, since you tell FF to draw to when it actually draw it it passes 5 secs? Are you sure it's not something else the bottleneck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue came form a CSS `setting`. The table had a `overflow:hidden` setting. Removing it helped and resolved my issue.